# When deploying a script, how to i make it apply to Sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I currently use a WebService to create Sales Orders, when a purchase is made on my site, in Netsuite.  I'm trying to apply my script deployment which updates some customer info when a sales order for that customer is created.

I'm trying to add the script for UserEvent afterSubmit and have it apply to "Sales Order" however I don't see this as an event type.  Is there something I need to enable to make this record type available in the "Applies To" field on Script Deployments?

This is NS 2.0.  I've tried applying it to "Customers" but because the integration I use creates a Sales Order, it doesn't trigger the script when it occurs.  Where I refer to the NetSuite docs, there should be a recordType called "salesOrder" but I don't see it when visiting Customization -> RecordTypes.

I except when a "Sales Order" is create through the webservice, my script is triggered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a drop down in the `Applies To` field dialogue under Script Deployment.  They are in alphabetical order

[image]

[image]

Comment: Search "Sales Order" in the above mentioned Applies To dialogue box. They are in alphabetical order and paginated.